# r twitteR package - pulling twits where user was tagged

Tags: r, twitter

I understand that I can pull twits from R using below two methods

```
searchTwitter("abc")#pulls all twits that contain keyword 'abc'
searchTwitter("from:abc") #pulls all twits from user 'abc'
```

1. **I want to pull twits where user was mentioned or tagged**. In twitter, while writing a twit     another user is mentioned or tagged by putting @ before the user's name. To achieve my goal should i use `searchTwitter("abc")` or
   should I use 'searchTwitter("@abc")'?
2. Is there a single command that could give me twits from the user
   `abc` as well as all twits where `abc` was tagged? I can always do
   two different searches - one `searchTwitter("abc")` and
   `searchTwitter("@abc")` (provided `@abc` returns all twits where
   user `abc` was mentioned or tagged) and then remove duplicate twtis.
   But I want to avoid that as it would involve a lot of duplication of
   twits. Twitter allows to pull only 18000 twits per 15 minutes and I
   would like to avoid pulling same tweets twice.

Answer (score 2):

You can pull all tweets from a single user using `userTimeline('user_name')`. You can define the number of tweets to query by adding `n=number` after the you define a users handle.

Example:

```
userTimeline('StackOverflow',n=5)

[[1]]
[1] "StackOverflow: @szalapski Hi Patrick! I just asked and our team says it's on their list to update the data AND make future updates… "

[[2]]
[1] "StackOverflow: If you want to see the code, check out Julia’s blog post below. @IBMcloud #DSX "

[[3]]
[1] "StackOverflow: Interested in text mining? Check out how Stack Overflow data scientist @juliasilge implements topic modeling using… "

[[4]]
[1] "StackOverflow: @martindaniel4 @Google "

[[5]]
[1] "StackOverflow: @Koprowski_it \xed��\xed�\u008d"
```

The query will also return https links but they had to be deleted for the post to go through here.

The book *R and Data Mining: Examples and Case Studies* by Yanchang Zhao has some excellent examples if your looking for a textbook walk through.

Comment: No, this is using timelines so it will only give you Tweets posted by the user. You'd want to use a compound query like `from:user OR to:user OR @user OR user`. The standard Twitter Search API documentation can help you here. https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/search/guides/standard-operators. You should also be aware that the standard Search API only provides access to the Tweets in a 7 day period backwards, and has an incomplete index.

Comment: would it be possible to show an example of a compound query? `from:user OR to:user OR @user OR user` - i didnt know that `to:user` is possible...currently i can write separate queries and join the data